# Docker in RedHat shows version as 1.13.1

Tags: rhel, docker, version

On trying to run build a docker image on my RHEL 7.6, I was getting the following error:

```
 Error parsing reference: "python:2 as build" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

On further investigation, I came across the below StackOverflow discussion that suggests updating docker to version >17.0.6.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48863391/6793637

The RHEL 7.6 docker version shows as given below.

[image]

but the current docker engine version is 19.03.1.

Could someone help me to solve the below doubts...

1. > Why is RHEL still has the older version or its just the naming difference?
2. > is 1.13.1 same as  17.03, as mentioned in the below discussion chain.?

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3381521

3. > Should I be installing the new docker-ce and if so how to do it?

Comment: What is the question? It is `docker-ce` that is version 17.03 and it's not supported by Red Hat. The latest version of `docker` for RHEL is 1.13.1-96. You have at least a minor release of that and you can just `yum update docker` to get it to the latest minor release. Red Hat supports that version and backports features into it rather than using the same naming convention as the others. It's unlikely that your issues with building your Docker image have anything to do with the version that you are using.

Comment: What's the difference between the two ?

Comment: Hi the issue was indeed the docker version , the new rhel instance doesn't have docker by default. I was able to update to latest docker and build the image thanks for the help.

Comment: No, it wasn't. You could have just changed the code to work with the supported Docker instead of installing one that Red Hat doesn't support. No operating system includes Docker by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is facing "From python:2" is not a valid tag error during defectdojo image building in RHEL.

Please follow the below resolution. Happy that was able to solve it.

RHEL uses old versions of docker , you have to install the latest docker engine. As 'FROM repo:tag" syntax is supported only from docker 17.06 and higher.

Docker installation in RHEL could be done using yum. Follow the exact steps

**Steps are outlined** @

`https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/`

**Defectdojo bug ID** :

`https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/issues/1442#issuecomment-517638657`

Comment: You are now running an unsupported version of Docker. It would have been better just to to change your code.

Comment: @ please suggest a different solution if 
 you feel its not the right approach https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3199282

Comment: I did. You can change the code in building your Docker image. I work as an IS Systems Engineer in an enterprise environment mostly with RHEL with many of the users working with Docker. Every system runs the supported Docker and not Docker-ce or Docker-latest and no one has any problems building images. Eventually, Red Hat will backport the changes into Docker provided that they don't cause any issues.

Comment: @NasirRiley its not my code, i am try to run a different product in RHEL.

Comment: It doesn't have to be your code. There is nothing stopping you from changing it or using something different if you aren't able to.

Comment: @NasirRiley could you please provide any official statement saying not use Docker CE. RHEL 8 doesn't even come with docker but uses podman

Comment: I have already told you that it's not supported by Red Hat. PHP, GCC, and HTTPD don't come preinstalled on RHEL either but they are available in Red Hat's repos just like Docker which means that they have support from Red Hat. Being supported doesn't mean that it comes preinstalled on the system.